# Is it possible to use a remote server to build Docker images but run locally?

Tags: docker

I set up a builder context to my server named `ec2` using

```
docker buildx create --name ec2 ssh://ec2
```

When I try to do any builds it just hangs there.  The command I use to do the build is

```
docker buildx use ec2
docker build .
```

When I do `docker buildx ls` it shows the status as `inactive`.

I'm on Windows so I am wondering if I am affected by the [Docker Desktop bug that spawns off many SSH connections](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-continuously-making-unnecessary-ssh-connections-to-remote-servers/136132).